# positive, neutral and negative words frequency

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have some corrections to do in my project before the final submission. I need to count the words that are positive, neutral and negative in my code.
I had earlier done the same thing when trying to find the word frequency in the text in which the output was okay.

```
def gen_freq(text):
    word_list=[] #stores the list of words
        
    for words in text.split(): #Loop over all the reviews and extract words into word_list
        word_list.extend(words)

    word_freq=pd.Series(word_list).value_counts() #Create word frequencies using word_list

    word_freq[:20]

     #Print top 20 word
    print(word_freq)
    return word_freq[:20]
      
gen_freq(dataset.text.str)
```

I have tried to do the same thing for generating word frequency for positive words:

```
def positive_freq(text):
    positive_list=[] #stores the list of words
        
    for words in text.split(): #Loop over all the reviews and extract words into word_list
        positive_list.extend(words)

    word_freq=pd.Series(positive_list).value_counts() #Create word frequencies using word_list

    word_freq[:20]

     #Print top 20 word
    print(word_freq)
    return word_freq[:20]
      
positive_freq(dataset.text.str)
```

I obtained the data using this code:

```
with open('reviews.json') as project_file:    
    data = json.load(project_file)
dataset=pd.json_normalize(data) 
print(dataset.head())
```

the output of the positive frequency is this:

```
and                   136
a                     127
the                   114
iPad                  102
I                      69
                     ...
"fully                  1
didn't.                 1
would                   1
instructions...but      1
these                   1
```

which should not be the case because the adjectives identified as positive are these:

```
Positive:
   polarity  adjectives
1  0.209881       right
1  0.209881         mad
1  0.209881        full
1  0.209881        full
1  0.209881        iPad
1  0.209881        iPad
1  0.209881         bad
1  0.209881   different
1  0.209881   wonderful
1  0.209881        much
1  0.209881  affordable
2  0.633333        stop
2  0.633333       great
2  0.633333     awesome
3  0.437143     awesome
4  0.398333         max
4  0.398333        high
4  0.398333        high
4  0.398333    Gorgeous
5  0.466667      decent
5  0.466667        easy
6  0.265146      itâ€™s
6  0.265146      bright
6  0.265146   wonderful
6  0.265146     amazing
6  0.265146        full
6  0.265146         few
6  0.265146        such
6  0.265146      facial
6  0.265146         Big
6  0.265146        much
8  0.161979         old
8  0.161979      little
8  0.161979        Easy
8  0.161979       daily
8  0.161979    thatâ€™s
8  0.161979        late
9  0.084762         few
9  0.084762        huge
9  0.084762  storage.If
9  0.084762         few
```

Also upon generation of the frequency, I wanted to plot a bar graph of the frequency against each word like if right has a frequency of 1, awesome has a frequency of 2, it should be shown on the graph. Likewise for the neutral and negative. Kindly help.

Comment: I think it's fine to ask this question, but the format makes it difficult to reproduce. An advice, simplify the question, go to the point (we don't need all the background info), provide a minimal reproducible input and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you expect the machine to know the positive/negative/neutral words. How do the machine know from .split() the positive words? you need to first provide a pre-define list of positive/negative/neutral words then after splitting you should check if each token exists in the lists. You could access such a list by sentimental dictionaries such sentiwordnet, or sentistrengh or a lot of others or existing python packages. Example:

```
from textblob import TextBlob

sent = 'a very simple and good sample'
pos_word_list = []
neg_word_list = []
neu_word_list = []

for word in sent.split():
    testimonial = TextBlob(word)
    if testimonial.sentiment.polarity >= 0.5:
        pos_word_list.append(word)
    elif testimonial.sentiment.polarity <= -0.5:
        neg_word_list.append(word)
    else:
        neu_word_list.append(word)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: hello @keramat, I had done the sentiments of the whole text and filtered the adjectives based on the polarity into positive, neutral and negative adjectives. So basing on the list of positive adjectives, that is where I was hoping to do the frequency count.

Comment: Hi @Madea you mean that your problem is to get the frequency of pos/neu/neg words, now?

Comment: Hello @keramat, I managed to get the frequency of the words.  All i had to do was:  ```positive_list= dataset.loc[dataset['polarity'] > 0.2, ['adjectives']]
print(positive_list)
#generating frequency of the positive words
pos_freq=positive_list.value_counts()
print(pos_freq)
``` Thank you